# Improving Visualforce Performance

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, performance

We have noticed that the initial load has a long delay but subsequent page loads are much faster.
 Is this some caching that is being done by salesforce internally or inside the ORg.
How long is the code/data cached?

Is there any way that performance can be measured at salesforce end?

Comment: There is a lot of content available on this, and it is a broad topic. Have you started with this whitepaper? https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Visualforce_Performance:_Best_practices

Comment: You can set caching by yourself. Take a look at the `cache` and `expire` params: [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes salesforce does cache lot of items including the static resources. But it all depends on how we create it.As #mast0r said setting cache value is one such case where the browser starts caching all the items.

Using third party library causes delays in page load , even if used from static resource.You can use chrome and Firefox's feature to find out the load times.

Thanks 
BK